# get stream of merged observables from another observable in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've a simple app which, based on a list of cities, retrieves some weather information from a service every X seconds and then displays the info.

I'm using Angular 4 with ngrx to accomplish that and I have it working, but I'd like to refactor some things into something more reactive.

So this is a piece of code that I want to change:

```
@Effect()
  weather$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_WEATHER_ACTION)
    .switchMap(() => {
      const cityObservables = this.cities.map(city =>
        this.service.getWeatherByCityId(city.id, city.name)
      );
      return Observable.merge(...cityObservables);
    })
    .map(weather => new CityWeatherLoadedAction(weather));
```

So the syntax here is not that important. What this is doing is, every time I get an action of type LOAD_WEATHER_ACTION, I create a list of observables, one for each city I want to get data for, and then I use merge to combine them all, and I use a switchMap to replace the initial observable stream for the new one.

All good, but what if my list of cities, instead of a simple array, is another observable? how would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you just `.switchMap` that Observable, and then do your `merge()` inside:

```
weather$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_WEATHER_ACTION)
    .switchMap(() => {
        return this.cities.switchMap((cities) => {
            return Observable.merge(...cities.map(city => this.service.getWeatherByCityId(city.id, city.name)))
        })

    })
    .map(weather => new CityWeatherLoadedAction(weather));
```